# Check if a tablet is connected to a power supply from a windows 8 store app

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

Is it possible from a Windows 8.1 store application to tell if the tablet has it's power supply connected.

Basically I poll a service every 15 minutes to check for new data but I'd like this to be every minute if the power is connected.

I did ask this question a while back and was told it wasn't possible but I was wondering if the windows 8.1 update has added any extra functionality.

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and the application is a Windows 8.1 application.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still no Power Management API or any alternatives for Windows 8.1

Check *System* section in this MSDN article:

[Alternatives to Windows APIs in Windows Store apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464945.aspx)